# ADO.NET or OLE for multiple databases?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have been tasked with a project at work of writing a class to connect to multiple different databases such as Oracle, SQL Server, Spatialite etc and get and set data values and I was wondering which of the two in the title you would recommend for this.

I have created a class that utilises OLE functionality in order to make connections and set and retrieve data as I thought ADO was more of an SQL Server specific technology. Is this the case or can ADO.NET be used for a variety of data sources? I have researched it quite a lot and most places that I have seen recommend OLE for multiple possible data sources whereas they recommend ADO for SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: Ok to make sure I understand what you are saying: It is ok to do the connections etc using OLE and then have seperate interfaces in order to run queries? At the moment I have a web service that handles calls for data and setting up connections etc using the OLE functionality and it can be accessed by a web page or a desktop app via its interface. Is this the correct way to go? By Multiple DAL's do you mean a different class for each type of data source? My initial approach was to have a service which had a class for each type but this is unfeasible as we are not supposed to know the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see how OLE is going to provide a magic bullet for unifying the DAL.  You want to use the data access framework that best suits the data source and abstract the implementation away from the application.

My guess is that you're hoping that using OLE will allow some unification of syntax.  But this is not the case.  Once you attempt to do something like paging, each data source is going to have its own quirks and how you connect to the source is not going to help unify the syntax differences.  For example, in the case of paging, SQLite usings SKIP, TAKE.  Oracle uses ROWNUM.  Sql Server uses TOP.

I would approach the problem by creating a DAL that abstracts the entity classes away from the data source. Then you can use the connection type that is most suitable for the data source. For example, suppose my application wants to retrieve "Products" from a data source.  My application would only know about the ProductFactory interface, not the specifics of the data source type.  For example,

```
string id = "0000001";
IProductFactory factory = FactoryManager.GetProductFactory();
Product p = factory.Get(id);
```

In the example below, I implement the Oracle data access tier for the Product interfaces using ODP.Net (the best data access components for an Oracle data source).  Then the data access tier looks like this:

[image: DAL]

**IProductFactory:**

```
public interface IProductFactory: IEntityFactory
{
    Product Get(string productId);
    IList<Product> GetAll();
    int GetAllCount();
}
```

**Product:**

```
public class Product : IEntity<Product>
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    #region IEntity<Product> Members

    public Product MapData(System.Data.IDataReader reader)
    {
        return new Product
        {
            Name = reader["name"] as string,
            Description = reader["description"] as string
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Oracle ProductFactory**

```
public class ProductFactory : EntityFactory, IProductFactory
{
    #region IProductFactory Members

    public Product Get(string productId)
    {
        Product p = null;
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from product where productId = :productId";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("productId", productId);
                using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    p = new Product();
                    p.MapData(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        return p;
    }

    public IList<Product> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public int GetAllCount()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I nearly upvoted you - good theoretical argument, 20 year outdated approah of then building the factory totally ignoring everything new since .NET 3.5 and LINQ. Factory<Product> should be all it takes.

Comment: Sure, one can substitute in the entity framework, LINQ, for the data access tier.  The sky is the limit.  In the case of Oracle, the native ODP.Net entity framework is still in beta, and it has quirks.  Sometimes all you need is a "product".  It's hard to know how complex the OP's data source is.

Comment: Not hoping to unify syntax as such. I have a WCF service that I have written a class into called oledbconnection.cs. This class handles connecting to a database and also has all the functions built in to run pure SQL and return results. I have it working on an oracle database and the only thing that appears to have to change is a connection string. Is it common for different databases to have different words for certain basic SQL functions such as SELECT etc?? The class will only be used for pure SQL so no calling of stored procedures etc.

Comment: Sounds like the DAL would hide behind your WCF service.  I really feel like you're barking up the wrong tree with an OLEDBConnection class.  You don't want the data source to be tied to OLEdb.  You want to have a data access tier that implements a particular interface.  *How* it connects to the database is of less consequence.  ORMs like the Entity Framework or NHibernate will guide you down such a path.  Perhaps my hand-coded sources are a bad idea.  But they get the point across, I think.  Yes, in my experience, SQL statements are going to vary by source.  As I said, paging is one example.

Comment: @Brett Thanks for all the infomation. I will take a look into what you suggest. What you say does seem very much like what I need. So you recommend entity framework or NHibernate to achieve the result I am looking for? Again thanks for the info. (Just re-read the posts higher up and the data source is fairly complex using spatial data which can be a real pain). See http://roadworksonline.org.uk/ This is the project I am involved in at the moment.

Comment: @CSharpened I have a feeling you'll get farther with NHibernate. To my knowledge, there aren't any great projects that support the Entity Framework to Oracle.  The best bet is ODP.Net, but it's in beta.  I ultimately abandoned it.  One hurdle with NHibernate is code generation for existing / legacy DBs.  The folks at CodeSmith have taken a reasonable pass at it.

Comment: Thanks for that Brett. I will consider my options and take a look into NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET can be used to connect to any database with an ODBC connection.  We use ADO.NET for pretty much everything (PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc), and it is the core database access method of most ORM products.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to abstract away the DAL (data access layer) through an interface, and then create multiple DALs one for each type of database.

Your task can become a lot easier if you use a provider based ORM such as Entity Framework for your DALs private code.

For the public part all you have to do is implement the interface contract and you're fine.